# OracleBI Discoverer Schema connection Error

Tags: oracle10g, connection, schema, administrator

I am creating a new custom SQL folder in Oracle discoverer administrator. Consider my Business Area is WORK schema is USER and table is ADDRESS. When i am using the query **"Select * from user.address;"**, it is showing error as table or view does not exists. But one day before i can execute the same query. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.. Somehow grant access to table got failed, so i can not access.. Again i grant access to tables now its ok..